# Is there a mapping of USB Flash Drives to Fat32 / NTFS / Ex-Fat?

Tags: ntfs, usb-flash-drive, controller, fat32, flash-drive

I am helping with documentation for a hardware product that is compatible with Fat32 Formatted USB sticks. Instead of saying "Fat32" and confusing users who may not be tech-savvy, we'd like to provide a list of compatible drives and brands.

Rather than researching each product separately, we hope that there is a smaller set of USB Controller Chips that determine the drive format, and that there might be a mapping from a few of these (e.g. "Fat32" controller chips) to products currently use them.

Does such a mapping exist?

Answer (score 1):

> Does such a mapping exist?

No, because such a relationship doesn't exist. Flash drives are block devices, and do not have any concept of supporting any one filesystem. One could just as easily format a flash drive as BTRFS or NTFS as they could FAT32, and none of those have anything to do with the chipset on a given flash drive.

If your product demands FAT32 to function, you must ensure that FAT32 is used on whatever block device you're using. If you're looking for pre-formatted FAT32 devices, you'd have to review the provided documentation for a given product to determine whether it comes that way.

Comment: Depending on how this is being used, you could have your hardware device format flash drives to make them compatible.